# The meta effect on closed questions

Tags: support, downvotes, closed-questions

Why can't I delete my own closed question which has answers? Why is it up to the mods as to whether it gets deleted. It's easy hunting for 'that meta effect', e.g. I've got two downvotes today on an old closed question within a short space of time.

*Why isn't voting closed on closed questions* and why can't a user delete a question instead of having to beg? If it's closed, it's a statement that it hasn't raised interesting discussion otherwise it wouldn't be closed.

Comment: Please clarify your problem -- you can't hold or delete your own question? You can't delete someone else's closed questions? Downvoted held questions can be voted to be closed I think after 3 days, or immediately if your rep is high enough, no?

Comment: See [Block downvoting a closed question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112749), [The "I Get It" Reputation Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552) and [What purpose does downvoting questions serve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1871)

Comment: And please don't use language like *wtf* in posts. There is no need to swear here.

Comment: Once the question has answers, you can't delete it, so you have to beg the mods for it to be deleted and your rep is in their hands.

Comment: When people have put effort in answers, why should the question asker get to chose to remove that effort from the site? The answerers didn't make the mistake of asking a low-quality question.

Comment: You can ask to be *disassociated* from a post instead of having it deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters because if people attempt to answer a low-quality question then they don't deserve the rep gained... There's loads of fence sitting already on that one, just like (I assume) refusing to delete and keeping the question for the benefit of search engines and to hell with its replaceable users.

Comment: @user3791372: You only get -2 per downvote, *that's really not that much*. If the answers are helpful to others, then those answers deserve to stay just as much.

Comment: If there are 'good answers', then the question shouldn't be closed. And it gives a big two-fingered salute to the questioner being downvoted due to that meta effect.

Comment: "only -2" is nothing when you have 286k rep

Comment: @user3791372 is your goal of asking questions to get rep or get the answer?  You shouldn't be asking questions just to earn rep.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Also, if answers are added to a low quality question and aren't taken away because question isn't deleted, that just encourages bottom-feeders to answer all types of low-quality questions for the rep.

Comment: @user3791372: you lost a total of 11 points to that question. I lose more on a regular basis to users being deleted and questions going with them. That's all par for the course. If you are here *just for the rep*, then you may be in the wrong place. I am trying to help people, presumably you post questions to get answers.

Comment: What does this have to do with the Meta effect? Did you link to the question from Meta?

Comment: @MartijnPieters et al. How did this turn to me being here for rep? If that were the case I'd have set up bots / shell accounts. My question has nothing to do with being here just for the rep.

Comment: @user3791372: then why all the upset over the downvotes?

Comment: @JoshCaswell, didn't they tell you? It's been observed that the Meta Effect has been spilling to other realms of late.

Comment: it follows that if a question is asked and it raises good answers, then it can't be a poor question. and as none of the answers are duplicates of the supposed duplicate question, then it also follows it can't be a duplicate question.

Answer (score 13):

You don't get to chose to destroy the efforts of others. If there are answers with upvotes on a question, then the OP doesn't get to unilaterally decide to take away that effort. The people posting the answers did not make the mistake of asking the question, after all.

You can instead ask to be disassociated from a post. Your name will be removed from the post, and it will no longer show up in your account. It is as if the post has been deleted. All reputation from votes (past and future) will be removed.

See [Could we have a Help Center page on disassociating posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239366/could-we-have-a-help-center-page-on-disassociating-posts) for a proposed help-center text that explains disassociation a little more:

> To request disassociation, use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page. In the form, say you want to disassociate a post and include the URL.

Comment: and rep is restored?

Comment: @user3791372: yes, rep is restored, I [found a reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192838/will-disassociating-a-post-from-my-account-remove-reputation-gains).